# Requirejs output to single file excluding jQuery not retaining dependency?

Tags: jquery, optimization, requirejs, require, gruntjs

I'm using the requirejs optimizer to minify my modules into one single file for production.
I want to however exclude jQuery from the file so it can be loaded separately from the actual application logic, how can I achieve this? I tried setting this up with the exclude and excludeShallow parameters, but when I run the page I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined app.min.js:14
>   (anonymous function) app.min.js:14

My grunt config for requirejs looks like this:

```
requirejs: {
        minify: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: 'js',
                mainConfigFile: 'js/main.js',
                name: 'main',
                out: 'js/app.min.js',
                excludeShallow: [
                    'jquery'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add in your app.min.js?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how:
http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty

In a build profile:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js",
    paths: {
        jquery: "empty:"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try capitalizing jQuery the same in app.min.js as in excludeShallow. I've run into similar problems before on *nix machines.

(Do you have app.min.js? That might help with figuring this out.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using some libraries which depends on jQuery. Are you using [shim option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to tell dependency?

I mean, your `js/main.js` has to contain configuration like below:

```
shim: {
  'some-library': ['jquery']
}
```